# use a xml output from a xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

I got an assignment, one of the questions asks us to produce a new XML output via XSLT, based on a new schema. Which I have already done it. The bonus of this question is, to produce a new xsl file to build a HTML table to rank the results based on a criteria from the output of the previous xsl file.

for example, In the original XML:

```
<PROPERTY>
<NAME>Abvc</NAME>
</PROPERTY>
```

and in the first xsl file, i have changed this to an xml output and rename the tags:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="pro">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="PROPERTY"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PROPERTY">
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

so my question is if I like to use the output from the **above xsl** file in **another xsl**, eg:

```
<xsl:template match="pro">
  //do something here...
</xsl:template>
```

Is it possible? btw I have to use the default xslt 1.0 version. It's the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple HTML output here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pro"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pro">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Header'"/>
                </th>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="./@name"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But how can you tell this result is retrieved from the output of another xsl file? Regards Zack

Comment: Hello Zack, sorry for my late answer. Yes, you can do that. It depends on the framework you are working with. Can you define more than 1 stylesheet to be called? That way the output of the first defined stylesheet would be passed to the second one. Hope that helps, Peter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's always possible to process the output of one stylesheet using another stylesheet. In large-scale applications it's an important way of creating modular structure and reusable components, usually referred to as "pipelining".

The mechanics of how you construct a pipeline depend on the technology you are using. You can control it using a Java program, using XProc, using Ant, or using a shell script. You can even do it by hand. There are many application frameworks such as Orbeon that provide pipelining support.